# How can I update to columns with the same value?

Tags: python, postgresql

Hi I would like to know is it possible to update two columns with just one value in python. Im wanting to `UPDATE` the levels table and update the two columns called `xp` and `total_xp` with the same value `len(str(message.content))*0.03)`,

Here is what I'm working with:

```
sql = ("UPDATE levels SET xp=%s, total_xp=%s WHERE guild_id = %s and user_id = %s")
            val = (exp + 2 + math.floor(len(str(message.content))*0.03), str(message.guild.id), str(message.author.id))
            cursor.execute(sql, val)
            conn.commit()
```

I would like to use the value `len(str(message.content))*0.03)` for both `xp` and `total_xp`

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some variables:

```
sql = "UPDATE levels SET xp=%s, total_xp=%s WHERE guild_id = %s and user_id = %s"
xp = total_xp = exp + 2 + math.floor(len(str(message.content))*0.03)
guild_id = str(message.guild.id)
user_id = str(message.author.id)
cursor.execute(sql, (xp, total_xp, guild_id, user_id))
conn.commit()
```